# How to convert Strings into polynomials and adding or subtracting them?

Tags: java

I have to represent the polynomials as arrayslist.How to take input from a txt file that looks like this

```
P1;5;3;-4;1;8;0
P2;6;5;-2;2;7;1;-4;0
```

and turn it into a polynomial that look like this

```
P1(X) = 5X^3 –4X +8
P2(X) = 6X^5 -2X^2 +7X -4.
```

And how could I solve addition and subtraction problems between these two polynomials? such as `P1 + P2`?

here is what i have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PolyProcessor {
    static int polyNum = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    PolyCalc c = new PolyCalc();
    File polyfile = new File("polyinput.txt");
    Scanner read = new Scanner(polyfile);
    while (read.hasNextLine()){
        String j = read.nextLine();
        c.add(j);
        }


    }
    }


class PolyCalc{
    static int polyCount = 0;

    static ArrayList polynomials = new ArrayList();

     static void add(String j){

         polynomials.add(j);
         polyCount++;}

     static Object get(int i){
         return polynomials.get(i);}


    }
```

Comment: This isn't as easy as you think. If it's homework, then create your own class that parse the String and creates an abstract representation of the polynomial. Otherwise, look for a library that handles this.

Comment: I have tried turning them into strings but after that I am clueless. I read them in, but have no idea how to use them after delimiting them. How can i even do math with an undefined variable. and then i have to add or subtract all the separate numbers maybe? I only have read them in and put them in the arraylist.

Comment: how do i make a representation?

Comment: Can the 'x' be substituted right away given a parameter?

Comment: I dont know.= what you mean

Comment: You can implement as sum of Maps where polynomial can be represented as key value pair in a mpa,key being power and value being coefficient

Comment: Made an answer @Dave

Answer (score 3):

**How does polynomial addition work?**

**Answer:- By adding the coefficients of same power**

**SO  P1 = 5X^3 - 4X + 8**

**and P2 = 6X^5 -2X^2 + 7X^1 + -4**

**becomes**

**P1 = 0X^5 + 5X^3 +0X^2 - 4X^1 + 8X^0**

**P2 = 6X^5 + 0X^3 -2X^2 + 7X^1 - 4X^0**

**____________________________________**

**SUM= 6X^5 + 5X^3 -2X^2 + 3X^1 + 4X^0**

**____________________________________**

You can store the power as Key and coefficient as value in a Map.Then iterate the maps and add the coefficients in their value

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SumOfPolynomials {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

     List<Map<Integer, Integer>> listOfPolynomials = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Integer>>();
    File polyfile = new File("polyinput.txt");
    Scanner read = new Scanner(polyfile);
    while (read.hasNextLine()){
        String LINE = read.nextLine();
        String[] lineSpillted =LINE.split(";");
        Map<Integer, Integer> poynomial = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i =1;i<lineSpillted.length-1;i=i+2){                //i starts from ignores P1,P2 etc

             poynomial.put(Integer.parseInt(lineSpillted[i+1]), Integer.parseInt(lineSpillted[i]));

        }
        listOfPolynomials.add(poynomial);
        }

    read.close();

    Map<Integer, Integer> result = polynomialSum(listOfPolynomials.get(0), listOfPolynomials.get(1));

    if(listOfPolynomials.size()>2){

        for(int i=2;i<listOfPolynomials.size()-1;i++){

            result = polynomialSum(result,listOfPolynomials.get(i));
        }
    }
    // print out the SUM as VALUEX^KEY
    System.out.println();
    int c = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {

        System.out.print(entry.getValue() + "X^" + entry.getKey());
        c++;
        if (c != result.size()) {
            System.out.print("+");
        }
    }

}

public static Map<Integer, Integer> polynomialSum(Map<Integer, Integer> arg1,
        Map<Integer, Integer> arg2) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> SUM = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : arg1.entrySet()) {

        Integer power = entry.getKey();
        Integer coeff1 = entry.getValue();
        Integer coefficient;
        if (arg2.containsKey(power)) {
            coefficient = arg2.get(power) + coeff1;
        } else {
            coefficient = coeff1;
        }
        SUM.put(power, coefficient);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : arg2.entrySet()) {

        if (SUM.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            continue;
        } else {
            SUM.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }

    return SUM;
}
```

}

**EDITED for multiple Polynomials.Multiple Polynomials are added in a List and then sum is calculated by iterating the List**

**Output:-**

[image: Output]

Comment: Ok i did but how do i read in the file and add or subtract them and return the output?

Comment: just use if (arg1.containsKey(power)) {
                coefficient = arg1.get(power) - coeff1;
            } else {
                coefficient = -1* coeff1;
            }

Comment: @Dave check your ployinput.txt.It should contain 2 lines,1 line for each polynomial.It works  perfectly for me

Comment: @Dave I have included the results for addition,you can add a parameter in the method ,say boolean wthere it is add or subtract and refractor your code accordingly

Comment: @Dave yes,,by adding a parameter to the method to tell whether it is add or subtract or resetting the coefficients

Comment: @Dave you can sort a map through its key in descending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60310/discussion-between-kumar-abhinav-and-dave).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea about how to implement the polynomial:

Based on the definition of [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial):

> In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression consisting of variables (or indeterminates) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents.

So, you can start by reducing the problem to a term:

```
class Term {
    //making it immutable
    final double power;
    final double coefficient;
    final String variable;
    //constructor
    public Term(double power, double coefficient, String variable) {
        //assign variables and such
        this.power = power;
        //...
    }
    //getters for your class
}
```

Now, create a `Polynomial` class as a `List` of terms and define necessary methods to add and remove terms:

```
class Polynomial {
    final String variable;
    List<Term> terms;
    public Polynomial(String variable) {
        //this will allow you to accept only "X" or "Y" or terms with this variable only
        this.variable = variable;
        terms = new ArrayList<Terms>();
    }
    public void add(Term term) {
        /*
            implement this...
        */
    }
}
```

With this basic model, you can come up with more ideas to enhance the design. For example, `Term` can implement `Comparable<Term>` in order to support comparison between terms, similar for `Polynomial` and other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to store the coefficients in an array, and let the indices of the array correspond to the powers on the `x` term. So an array of:

`{2, 4, -1, 1}`

Would translate to:

`x^3 - x^2 + 4x + 2`

Then adding and subtracting would simply be a matter of adding corresponding indices between two arrays, and storing the result in a new array. You would also have to keep track of the highest power term of the polynomial so you would know how how big to make the array that represents it. So a polynomial of order `n` would have an array of size `n + 1` to represent it.

Comment: How does that array you made translate to that?

Comment: You multiply the number in the array times `x` to the power of the index of that number in the array. So for example, `-1` in the array has an index of `2`, so it becomes `-1 * x^2`, or simply `-x^2`.

Comment: @Dave His first array element is the last coefficient (`2x^0`). I expect that he chose that order because it's easiest to grow outward and the index gives the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the variable names not being anything close to being mathematical standards nor has this been tested, but this should leave you with some sort of idea.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Poly {

    private String[] numbers;
    private ArrayList<Variable> func;

    public Poly(String poly, double valueOfX) {
        numbers = poly.split(";");
        func = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length - 1; i+=2) {
            double exp = (numbers[i+1] == "0") ? 1 : Double.parseDouble(numbers[i++]); 
            double x = (numbers[i+1] == "0") ? 1 : valueOfX; 
            func.add(new Variable(Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]), exp, x));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Variable> getFunc() {
        return func;
    }

}
public class Variable {

    private double value;
    private double exponent;
    private double x;

    public Variable(double value, double exponent, double x) {
        this.value = value;
        this.exponent = exponent;
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public double getExponent() {
        return exponent;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

From this, you are then able to get the variables you want and calculate values by getting the index of the arraylist and work some magic.

Comment: I just realised that it will incorrectly evaluate the last number as anything to power of 0 is 1.

Comment: So does this separate the variables and the coefficients and exponents? does it take the first 3 letters pn1 and mistakes them for integers?

Comment: @Dave I made the mistake of not adding the x part into the equation. I am not near a compiler to test this sorry but hopefully this works.

Comment: You can access each element through the getFunc() method which in turn you can access all the getters for Variable.

Comment: @Dave, this also assumes that the string is like p1;1;2;2;1;4;0 etc as it will ignore the p1 and purely add the values in.

Comment: are you able to explain how this code would work exactly. like after reading the file? why does it say class Variable needs to be in a separate file even though i removed public from it.

Comment: Okay, this work doesn't cover reading from a text file. I don't remember the functions at the top of my head to do that. However, if you are able to get that String from a text file (e.g. P1;5;3;-4;1;8;0) then you simply do Poly name = new Poly("P1;5;3;-4;1;8;0", anyDoubleValueForX); This will load all the values into the ArrayList that has been constructed. Going with the String above, getValue() for index 0 represents 5, getX()=anyDoubleValueForX, getExponent() = 3. To access them, just simply do name.getFunc().get(0).getValue(); and so on and use those values to work it out with a math lib.

Comment: I am not near a computer at the moment so it is untested. However I hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: I did what you said. I just dont know how i would read like 3 lines in and then add or subtract the polys and stuff i am just confused a little.

Comment: @Dave I just realised a bug with it and have made minor fixes. As for the readingmultiple lines, maybe you can have multiple Poly's like Poly p1 = new Poly("P1;5;3;-4;1;8;0", xValue); Poly p2 = new Poly("P2;6;5;-2;2;7;1;-4;0", yValue); etc.

Comment: Good luck with it, I need to go somewhere.